# terraform init Registry service unreachable

Tags: terraform

I am trying to build a VM using terraform from my office's network. I am getting the following error because the server doesn't have internet access. Is there anyway I can download the plugins offline?

```
Initializing provider plugins...
- Checking for available provider plugins...

Registry service unreachable.

This may indicate a network issue, or an issue with the requested Terraform Registry.


Error: registry service is unreachable, check https://status.hashicorp.com/ for status updates
```

Answer (score 6):

**Note:** The instructions in this comment were correct when I originally wrote it, but the situation changed slightly from Terraform v0.13 and later because Terraform now supports automatic installation from multiple namespaces in multiple registries.

You can find more information about configuring automatic plugin installation for modern Terraform in [the CLI Configuration documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/config/config-file.html), specifically in [the Provider Installation section](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/config/config-file.html#provider-installation).

I've preserved the content below, and it remains *roughly* true for modern Terraform in that Terraform still supports `-plugin-dir` as a legacy alternative to the `provider_installation` settings, but the content below is mainly useful only for Terraform v0.12 and earlier.

---

By default Terraform makes requests to `registry.terraform.io` to find provider plugins. If you are running Terraform in a context where it cannot access services over the internet *directly* then you can indeed ask Terraform to run in a local-only mode with regard to plugins.

To do that, first locate the provider plugin executables you wish to use. At the time of writing those are on [releases.hashicorp.com](https://releases.hashicorp.com/), though that location might change in future.

Extract the zip files you downloaded into a single directory, so you end up with a flat directory with only executable files in it named something like this:

```
terraform-provider-aws_v2.0.0
terraform-provider-null_v1.0.0
terraform-provider-template_v2.0.0
```

Once you've populated this plugin directory, you can run `terraform init` with the extra option `-plugin-dir`, passing the path to the directory you just populated. For example:

```
terraform init -plugin-dir=/opt/terraform/plugins
```

When you use `-plugin-dir`, this disables Terraform's automatic discovery and download functions and instructs it to look *only* in this local directory. `terraform init` will return errors if any of the necessary plugins aren't in that directory, in which case you can download these extra plugins into your directory to fix that.

Note that Terraform plugins are versioned, and Terraform will only accept a plugin that matches the version constraints given in the configuration. Normally the auto-install behavior can select a suitable version automatically, but when you are downloading plugins manually yourself you will need to select suitable versions.

Terraform has a command `terraform providers` which will print out the provider requirements for the current configuration, as a prompt to help you decide which versions to download.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, I have downloaded the plugins and executed below command and it worked                                                             terraform init -input=false -plugin-dir=/usr/lib/custom-terraform-plugins

Comment: Will setting -plugin-dir to /dev/shm/ or a similarly empty directory make it COMPLETELY DISABLE the code that makes terraform arbitrarily go out and check for updates?  Asking for a friend working in an Enterprise shop where they like to schedule the surprise parser changes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. But i created the example.tf file in a folder where i had the binary for terraform download as shown below.

C:\Terraforms

terraform_0.12.18_windows_amd64

terraform_0.12.18_windows_amd64.zip

example.tf

and from this folder i executed the "terraform init" command which results in above error.
To fix this, simply i created one more folder here

C:\Terraforms

terraform_0.12.18_windows_amd64

terraform_0.12.18_windows_amd64.zip

app

and in "app" folder i placed my terraform.tf file. Then i went onto "app" directory and executed the command which worked.

Comment: How does this resolve the problem of not having Internet access from the location running terraform and needing to pull the plugins from an alternate location?

Answer (score 0):

also, you can set the debug mode to have more insights, you can do that setting TF_LOG environment variable to "TRACE" for example:

TF_LOG=TRACE terraform init

https://www.terraform.io/docs/internals/debugging.html

I had a similar issue than yours, in my case I realized that it's because I use Mac and there is an known issue on the terraform version than I'm using at the moment

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/26716